# How to get view to fill remaining width in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I'm using fxml in JavaFX and I want a list master/detail view. A list on the left of a fixed size, and a detail of a TextArea where the width grows with the window size.

This is my fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <MenuBar prefWidth="671.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <HBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ListView prefHeight="754.0" prefWidth="236.0" />
            <TextArea />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

This sample fxml looks like this:
[image]

You can see that the list is correct, and the textArea is showing and growing in height but not in width.

**EDIT**

Modified due to an answer.

This is the full code now. I only changed the max width and height of -Infinity to -1 but still no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-1" maxWidth="-1" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <top>
        <MenuBar prefWidth="671.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <HBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <ListView prefHeight="754.0" prefWidth="236.0" />
                <TextArea />
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [`HBox.hgrow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setHgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-) property of the text area:

```xml
<TextArea HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
```

Comment: What about the suggested answer from sillyfly. Is that needed as well?

Comment: @EGHDK I tested it with just the change I suggested; seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The value of negative infinity is the constant [USE_PREF_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/constant-values.html#javafx.scene.layout.Region.USE_PREF_SIZE), which means your `BorderPane` will never be larger than its preferred size (which in your case is 1280x800).

Changing the maximum width and height to [USE_COMPUTED_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/constant-values.html#javafx.scene.layout.Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE) (-1) should solve your problem. As this is the default value, you could just remove the `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` attributes.

Comment: Edited my question. I made your suggested changes, but it still doesn't act right.